# Running rails new and getting an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to start a new rails project and I am getting this error message!

```
 Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/coffee-script-2.2.0.info An error occurred while installing coffee-script (2.2.0), and Bundler cannot continue. 
  Make sure that `gem install coffee-script -v '2.2.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

everything was fine until I upgraded to the mavericks OS. could that be the root of the problem?

Comment: Apparently you cannot write to the `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/build_info/` folder. Try and fix that..

Comment: are you using rvm? You very well might be and this isn't being picked up in your install

Comment: Try reinstalling rvm then come back

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I did a bundle update then I used sudo to start a new rails app and it worked, thanks for the help. Also I had tried uninstalling RVM but when i tried to install it back i couldn't because i am using the new Maverick os.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out, I did a bundle update then I used sudo to start a new rails app and it worked, thanks for the help. Also I had tried uninstalling RVM but when i tried to install it back i couldn't because i am using the new Maverick os.